# How to forward ngTemplate to wrapped PrimeNg table

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-table

For an Angular application I want to create a table component that wraps a PrimeNG table. For this table component it should be possible to define a body template. Therefore I need to somehow forward the body template to the wrapped PrimeNG table, but I cannot figure out how to achieve that.

Following is a simplified version of my table component that wraps the PrimeNG table:

```js
import { AfterContentInit, Component, ContentChildren, Input, QueryList, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
import { PrimeTemplate } from "primeng/api";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-my-table',
    template: `
        <p-table
            *ngIf="bodyTemplate"
            [value]="value"
        >
            <ng-template pTemplate="caption">
                {{title}}
            </ng-template>

            <ng-template pTemplate="header">
                <tr>
                    <th *ngFor="let h of headers">{{h}}</th>
                </tr>
            </ng-template>

            <!-- here should bodyTemplate go, but how? -->
            <ng-template pTemplate="body" [ngTemplateOutlet]="bodyTemplate"></ng-template>

        </p-table>
    `
})
export class MyTableComponent implements AfterContentInit {

    @ContentChildren(PrimeTemplate) templates!: QueryList<PrimeTemplate>;

    @Input() title: string = '';
    @Input() headers: string[] = [];
    @Input() value: any[] = [];

    bodyTemplate: TemplateRef<any> | undefined;

    ngAfterContentInit() {
        this.templates.forEach((item) => {
            switch (item.getType()) {
                case 'body':
                    this.bodyTemplate = item.template;
                    break;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And the following is how it should be used (I use the pTemplate directive to get the TemplateRef for the body template, in the same way as PrimeNG does that).

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
      <app-my-table
          title="My table"
          [headers]="headers"
          [value]="data"
      >
          <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-item>
              <tr>
                  <td>{{item.a}}</td>
                  <td>{{item.b | uppercase }}</td>
                  <td>{{item.c | percent }}</td>
              </tr>
          </ng-template>
      </app-my-table>`,
})
export class AppComponent {

    headers = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
    data = [
        { a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 0.0},
        { a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 0.1},
        { a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 0.2},
        { a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 0.3},
        { a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 0.4},
        { a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 0.5},
    ];
}
```

I tried to insert `bodyTemplate` with `<ng-template pTemplate="body" [ngTemplateOutlet]="bodyTemplate"></ng-template>`, but that doesn't work. It might be an issue with a missing context (the error reads `"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'a')"`), but maybe I am just doing it wrong :).

Does anyone know how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ngTemplateOutlet` use with `ng-container` not `ng-template`

should be

`<ng-container pTemplate="body" *ngTemplateOutlet="bodyTemplate; context: { $implicit: row}"></ng-container>`

and wrap it inside `p-table` default body template

`<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-row>`

> ```
>         <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-row>
>           <ng-container pTemplate="body" *ngTemplateOutlet="bodyTemplate; context: { $implicit: row}"></ng-container>
>         </ng-template>
> ```

Demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tabledoc-demo-6k357a?file=src/app/my-table.component.ts)

Comment: That is amazing, thank you so much. I will need some time to digest this though, although I think I get it, I am not  entirely sure if I correctly understand why this works :).